# File upload not working using URLRequest in flex

Tags: apache-flex, html, actionscript

I used upload functionality by html . using given code it's working fine .

```
     <form id="avatar" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
           action="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/slingshot/profile/uploadavatar?
                  alf_ticket=TICKET_7475e180e8d258c0341fc745a3a35274d0a06e50" 
           method="post">

     <input type="text" name="username" value="ken"/>
```

Select a file:

```
    <input type="file" name="filedata" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="upload" / /form
```

Same functionality I have tried in flex :

```
var uploadURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest();          
uploadURL.url="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/slingshot/profile/uploadavatar?alf_ticket=TICKET_7475e180e8d258c0341fc745a3a35274d0a06e50"";
uploadURL.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
uploadURL.contentType="multipart/form-data";
var params:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
params.username ="admin";
params.filedata=fileRef.data;
uploadURL.data = params;
fileRef.upload(uploadURL)
```

BUT GETTING Bad request error . so anybody know , what did i wrong in code . Please share with me .

Comment: Did you check what are you sending to server?Try installing www.charlesproxy.com and check what is in your request and response object. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a POST request you are trying to send a  parameter in URL..try sending alf_ticket as an attribute of params.

Comment: i tried as u said , but still not working ...  thanks for your response

Comment: if i tried using flex based form to upload file . then it's working fine .